# How do I apply an Ambient Occlusion material "multiplied" over a base color (principled BSDF shader)

Tags: materials, shader-nodes, ambient-occlusion

In [Modo](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo), I could take a basic Ambient Occlusion (AO) layer and apply it over whatever material layer I had underneath (the way you would apply a multiply layer in photoshop) this would add a nice base layer of shadow to the material that I could adjust as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect it by adding an *Ambient Occlusion Node* (under *input*) and multiply it over your *BaseColor* using a *MixRGB Node*. If your material has a normal map, connect it to the normal input of the *AO Node*. Don't forget to enable Ambient Occlusion in the render properties panel (right side):

[image: AO]

Comment: Thank you very much @ChristopherBennett.  Could you zoom out so that I could study your entire node tree?

Answer (score 0):

Tried the approach above and it worked well.
In my case, perhaps because the normal map is not particularly detailed, I followed a simpler approach with AO that worked better (I have an AO texture map).

- Get a "mixRGB" node and change it from mix to multiply.
- Connect Color output to Base Color input in Principled BSDF node.
- Connect Ambient Occlusion texture map to color2 input and Base color texture map to color1 input.
- Change Fac slide until you are happy with the amount of AO displayed. Left it in 1.000 in my case.

Hope it helps!
[image]